# Winter Bash Icon broken on Apps Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, winter-bash-2012

On the My Apps page of the user profile, the icon for Winter Bash is broken:

[image: Apps Page]

The image points [here](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/icon-50.png) which gives a 404.

Comment: That event is over and the image has been removed. What would you *have* us do? My suggestion would be: use a url that isn't dead... am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Marc: I don't understand your comment. Isn't Winter Bash (and thus that link) under SE control? Are you saying we should just remove that app because it won't happen again (or if a similar event happens, it'll be a different app)?

Comment: See the "remove" link?  Click it.  Only one more week till spring.

Comment: @Marc we never added that app manually it was added by code you (Stack Exchange team) wrote so the URL is... yours.

Answer (score 7):

That link works for me...you guys are crazy with your 404 claims

Comment: You... you... you... thanks!

Comment: And the 50 point reward goes to...

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, had to wait 24 hours!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why yours isn't working. Can you get the actual URL of the image it is trying to find?

Here is mine: http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/icon-50.png

See how yours compares.

[image]

Comment: Nick fixed this by restoring the deleted icon.